# How to create a RichTextbox control from scratch?

Tags: c#, controls

I need to know is it possible to create a textbox or richtextbox in C# from scratch, not extending anything, just building from root up?

how can it be done? ideas?

Comment: Winforms, WebForms, WPF, what?

Comment: Personally, there are better more "modern" text format than RTF. OpenXml, OpenDoc, or even plain Html. Or heck, you could even use Markdown (like StackOverflow) if you want basic formatting.

Comment: He might as well implement his own embeddable web browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at codeproject [AvalonEdit](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/edit/AvalonEdit.aspx)

Comment: If I remember correctly, their text editing control is implemented "from scratch", deriving from Control. The control handles key input, caret positioning and blinking, and much much more.

Answer (score 4):

It can be done, but it would be insanity.

Here's all you need to agree:

Step 1: read the latest [Rich Text Format specification](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=DD422B8D-FF06-4207-B476-6B5396A18A2B&displaylang=en) (12MB Word document - 279 pages)

Comment: Upvoted for linking to the RTF format.  I've consulted the spec.  It's big.  Generating a valid RTF doc from scratch is hard enough.  Parsing it and formatting text for display is many times harder.

Comment: Ditto.  So much junk on the internet, this link DEFINITELY needs to be shared a lot more.